# How to send email with log output if script fails

Tags: bash, shell-script, lftp

I have the following script template I've been writing to use LFTP to mirror remote files to a local folder for clients. If the mirror fails, I'd like it to send an email with the output that was logged (but not the actual log file, as it could be rather long). As is, it would only show the exit status of 1. What's the best way to send the output instead?

```
#! /bin/bash

# Client info
client=example
data=/home/clients/$client/data
log=/home/clients/$client/log

# Create directories
mkdir -p $data $log

# LFTP settings
protocol="sftp://"
host="ftp.example.com"
user="example"
pass='123abc'
remote=/Outbound
command="mirror --verbose --continue $remote $data"

# Output to log
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>>$log/$client.log 2>&1

# Begin import | Recursively mirror remote to data
timestamp="$(date +"%m-%d-%Y@%T")"
echo "*** Time is $timestamp ***"
echo "Starting $client import."   
lftp -u $user,$pass $protocol$host <<EOF
set net:timeout 5
set net:max-retries 2
set net:reconnect-interval-base 5
$command
bye                                                     
EOF

#Store import exit status
import_exit_status=$?

# Send notification if feed import fails
if [ $import_exit_status -ne 0 ]; then
  /usr/sbin/sendmail "example@domain.com" <<EOF
subject:$client Import Failed
from:notifications@host
Import failed with following reason(s):
$import_exit_status
EOF
else
  echo "Import complete."
  echo ""
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Is the question "how do I only log output for a single interaction, so I can send it" (use a temporary file), or "how do I send email" (use e.g. the command `mail`, but you need a configured MTA on your system)?

Comment: As is, the email sends, and the output is appended to the log file. What I need help doing is, in the email body, replacing $import_exit_status with the output from this session - or even just the LFTP error. I'm no expert at scripting so I'll take any advice I can get if I've done this in an over complicated way. Thanks!